# Get OS X Chrome to accept self-signed SSL certificate for localhost

Tags: macos, mac, google-chrome, ssl, certificate

I've been trying to get this working all day, and I have a strong feeling that my issue is specific to Yosemite. I'm running OS X 10.10.3 on a retina Macbook Pro.

I took instructions from http://www.robpeck.com/2010/10/google-chrome-mac-os-x-and-self-signed-ssl-certificates/

But while that does indeed fix the errors thrown by Safari, it does not fix the issue in chrome. I can "proceed anyways" but the red crossed out lock is not going away. I want to implement a feature in a web app that requires SSL support in Chrome specifically, but I can't test it locally due to this issue.

Does anyone know why this is happening? Or if it's not even possible to do this?

Comment: I have the same issue. I think mine stems from the fact that the machine I'm trying to access [a gateway/router] doesn't have a fully-qualified domain name & Chrome objects to that. Safari is fine with it after the method you linked, just not Chrome.

Comment: Check here for answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580508/getting-chrome-to-accept-self-signed-localhost-certificate

Answer (score 3):

Try enabling the "Allow invalid certificates for resources loaded from localhost" flag in chrome, enter "chrome://flags" in the URL box of chrome, search for "invalid" (part of above flag name), click enable, and restart Chrome.

Comment: Nice tip. Never knew this flag existed.

Comment: Mine is not on localhost